# Discrete Subgroups of the Complex Numbers

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to show that if $G$ is a discrete subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{C}$ then $G$ is one of $\{0\}$, $\omega_1\mathbb{Z}$ and $\omega_1\mathbb{Z} + \omega_2\mathbb{Z}$, where $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ are linearly independent. Here's what I have so far:

First note that there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that each member $\omega \in G$ has the property that $\mathbb{B}(\omega, \epsilon) \cap G = \{\omega\}$. If $G = \{0\}$ we are done; otherwise let $\omega_1$ have the smallest length in $G \setminus \{0\}$. From the minimality,
$$G \cap \omega_1\mathbb{R} = \omega_1\mathbb{Z}.$$
If $G \setminus \omega_1\mathbb{Z} \neq \varnothing$, similarly pick $\omega_2 \in G \setminus \omega_1\mathbb{Z}$ of minimal length. We can similarly argue that
$$G \cap \omega_2\mathbb{R} = \omega_2\mathbb{Z}.$$
I now need to show that here $G = \omega_1\mathbb{Z} + \omega_2\mathbb{Z}$. My current idea consists of taking $\omega_3 \in G \setminus (\omega_1\mathbb{Z} + \omega_2\mathbb{Z})$ and deriving a contradiction, but that's where I'm stuck. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to find a combination of $\omega_1,\,\omega_2,\,\omega_3$ that is shorter than $\omega_2$.

Comment: That is my first thought (in fact it is sufficient to have a combination of the three that is shorter than $\omega_3$), but I don't see an obvious way of doing this.

Comment: Well, $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ form a basis in $\mathbb C$. We decompose $\omega_3$ in that basis to some $a\omega_1+b\omega_2$. Now let's shift that until $a,\,b\in(-{1\over2},{1\over2}]$.

Comment: Right. So if $\omega_3 = \alpha\omega_1 + \beta\omega_2$ with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$, we should be able to prove that $\omega_3 - a\omega_1 - b\omega_2$ is shorter than $\omega_2$ where $a, b$ are the closest integers to $\alpha, \beta$. After drawing a diagram this seems clear, but I can't think of a way to prove this. Might be missing something obvious.

Comment: Say, $\omega_3=\alpha\omega_1+\beta\omega_2$. Now find the integers $a,\;b$ such that $\omega_3' =  - a\omega_1 - b\omega_2=\alpha'\omega_1+\beta'\omega_2$, where $\alpha',\,\beta'\in(-{1\over2},{1\over2}]$. Then you'll have your estimate on $|\omega_3'|$.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Writing it out made it obvious, thanks.